# Double the Variance of each component in R

Tags: r, random, covariance, variance

I am trying to see how my scatter plot changes when I "double the variance in each component." I know how to find the variance of my samples, but I am confused on how I double them.

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)

x<-mvrnorm(n=100, mu=c(0,0),Sigma=diag(2)) # 100 samples from a 2D normal variable with identity covariance matrix
print(x)
colnames(x)<-c('x1','x2')
x<-data.frame(x)
ggplot(x,aes(x=x1,y=x2))+geom_point()
```

Normally I would take 2 variables, find the variance of each of them, calculate the covariance, and use that in the above equation, but I believe this method to be wrong.

Comment: Right now, `Sigma = diag(2)` is your covariance matrix. You can double it with `Sigma = 2 * diag(2)`.

Comment: That was my first thought. But I guess the answer is simple then: the variance doubles or the spread of the scatter plot. How would I change my original "x" instead of creating a new one? This way I can show the change more easily.

Comment: If you look at [the Basic Properties of Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) (wiki link), I bet you can figure it out. It helps that your mean is 0.

Comment: We are not doubling each $x_i$. I understood the question as 2*Var(x1) and 2*Var(x2). What then happens to the scatter plot?

Comment: Well, by the properties of variance, doubling the `x_i` would 4x the variance - you should multiply the `x_i` by `sqrt(2)` to double the variance. But I'm confused - I first suggested doubling your variance with `Sigma = 2 * diag(2)`. You don't like that, you say *"How would I change my original "x" instead of creating a new one?"*, so I point you to the solution that `x = sqrt(2) * x` will double the variance, but you say  *"We are not doubling each $x_i$"*. You either need to modify the data directly, or modify the procedure to generate the data. Pick one.

Comment: Sigma = 2 * diag(2) doubles the covariance. I think I am looking for a general solution. So for any 2D Gaussian with mean [0,0] and identify covariance, what happens when their variances doubles? The variance doubling effects the covariance. 2 * diag(2) doubles the covariance. Does doubling the variance directly doubles the covariance?

Comment: Because your covariance matrix is diagonal, there is no pairwise covariance except by randomness - your components are independent. The diagonal elements of the covariance matrix are the variances of each component, so doubling them doubles the variances of each component by definition.

Comment: That makes sense now. So the answer is as simple as the spread of the distribution doubles.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "spread". The variance doubles (clearly). The individual values, on average, are `sqrt(2)` farther from the mean, and the standard deviation is also multiplied by `sqrt(2)`.